# NextJS to ElectronJS

Tags: next.js, electron, next.js13

I have a web app in NextJS and TypeScript working fine. Now, I want to move it to ElectonJS so I can move from the web and create desktop app versions. I have tried different approaches but nothing worked for me. I also failed to find a good documentation or article about migrating NextJS to ElectronJS.
I am using [nextron](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron) but I can also use some other if recommended.

Approach 1: I created a new nextron app using "yarn create nextron-app my-app basic-typescript" command as mentioned on nextron guide. Then I moved the whole code inside the renderer directory but it is showing an error when I compile. [Error in Approach 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezoMO.jpg)
Approach 2: I created a dummy nextron app and install all necessary dependencies there, then I copied the files, dependencies etc to my NextJS app and moved the pages folder to renderer along with the necessary files but it is also showing error.[Error in Approach 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exa2a.jpg)
[My NextJS App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaO9R.png)

Can anyone help please?